# Report SSIS success when loop fails

Tags: loops, error-handling, ssis

I have a package that has a loop in it, that loops through a few connections. Each iteration through the loop is a new connection. The problem is though that sometimes these connections are down at package run time. So I've added an on error, send us an email notification, and then continue with the loop.

This works fine, using the `Event Handlers` and changing the `Propagate` value to `False`. But the issue is, if a connection fails, it will finish the loop, but report the entire package fails. This is an issue because inside a job in SSMS, it will stop the job after that package is complete, and report it failed, when it really did not.

Is there a way to have the package report success even if this loop kicks out the failed e-mail? I don't want it "Continue to next step on fail" because there are other parts to that package that could legit fail, and need to be notified on.

EDIT:

Here are screen shots of what I'm doing. Inside the loop there is a `dataflow` task, the first `dataflow` has the connection that sometimes fails. When it does, it triggers the email task to notify us, then will continue with the loop.

Unfortunately the `FailPackageOnFailure` is already set to false.

[image: Loop]

[image: Properties]

Comment: A screenshot would have been **really** useful to understand what you are trying to achieve! Highlight which part you want to continue on fail.

Comment: See screen shots above.

Answer (score 0):

On the task that fails (or its parent container if applicable), change the value of `FailPackageOnFailure` to false.

If you are doing this to a task in a loop, you may want to consider whether you also need to set `FailParentOnFailure` to false as well.

EDIT:   If none of your tasks or containers are causing the package to fail with `FailPackageOnFailure`=true, then probably you are setting the package to fail in a script.   Maybe in your event handlers you are keeping a count of errors, and then at the end of the package you are setting the package state to failure if the error count <> 0.

Examine **all** the points at which you could be setting the package to fail, either through a script or through the `FailPackageOnFailure` property.

Comment: Unfortunately the `FailPackageOnFailure` is already set to false. See my screen shots in my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can fake the execution result to success by setting the property **ForceExecutionResult** to **Success** (Default value of this property is **None**) for the Foreach Loop Container.